# Connecting double vanity do single drain with distance above 30inches

Tags: drain

I purchased double vanity and thought I will be able to just connct it using single trap to existing 1 1/2 wall drain
After some reading I found out that this is only allowed when distance is less than 30" between drains and in my case it is going to be around 41" (I am in Illinois, I assume this rule still applies).
I don't know what is happening in the wall or where the stack is. Any proposal how can i connect it correctly?
Do I have to open the wall and add 2nd drain outlet as shown on the picture?
Thanks
[image: diagram]

[image: adding 2nd drain option]

Answer (score 1):

This may be dipping into a gray area of rules.  I will defer to any professional plumbers to give a final ruling.

In lieu of opening the wall and moving the drain pipe, I would add a 90 deg sweep and move the drain 10 inches or more to the left.

Then I would add another 90 and a wye and the P-trap connections, so technically (maybe) neither sink has a drain more than 30 inches from the discharge drain.

Of course maintain the proper slope, and add the necessary 45 deg. 0r 22 1/2 deg. fittings to get the traps aligned.

Comment: @Arek you would add the angles and Wye under the cabinet, not in the walls. Unless, of course, you _want_ to open up the wall to do so.

Comment: My answer was assuming you did NOT want to open the wall and the work was done under the vanity.  YES...if you are opening the wall then it is a simple task of adding the second drain.

Comment: @Arek...if you knew what you needed to do WHY did you ask a question as if you were at a loss s to how to overcome the problem?

Comment: Thanks both. I would prefer to avoid opening the wall but also don't want to have drain problems or enter Grey area of code. As I have drawers in the vanity also not sure if I have all the space needed for all the connections. What do you mean by having traps aligned?

Comment: Thanks @RMDman. I didnt knew what to do. Looking for best option to install it, ideally without opening the walls.

Comment: Doing it under the cabinet instead of inside the wall will be quite handy when it clogs up. And, someday, it will.